# Java Swing GridBagLayout - Issue with placing two elements on a panel

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

**First i'll show you how it is**:

[picture_how_it_is](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/652/howitis.jpg)

**This is how it should be** (see link below in my comment):

Label has to be up and TabPane has to fill the rest of the screen with margins in all directions.

This is the code for laying it out with GridBagLayout:

```
// Layout --begin--
    this.mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    // Layout:headLineLabel --begin--
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    gbc.ipady = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    this.mainPanel.add(this.headLineLabel, gbc);
    // Layout:headLineLabel --end--

    // Layout:FestplattenreinigerGraphicalUserInterfaceTabbedPane --begin--
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    gbc.ipady = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    this.mainPanel.add(new FestplattenreinigerGraphicalUserInterfaceTabbedPane(), gbc);
    // Layout:FestplattenreinigerGraphicalUserInterfaceTabbedPane --end--
    // Layout --end--
```

Things you need to know:

1. FestplattenreinigerGraphicalUserInterfaceTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane.
2. I tried to specify all constraints (even with their default-val) to practice.
3. If I commend out the achors, layout remains how it is.

What's wrong in this thing?

THX very much!  (sorry i couldnt post images directly + only 1 link due to i'm new -.-)

Comment: How it should be: http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/6905/howitshouldbe.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have left out weightx and weighty which are necessary or everything will just lump together in the middle. So before adding the tabpane add:

```
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
```

Comment: thx man. after setting up the weightings, when i resized the window tabpane and the label had a very big margin to each other. now i put them in the same x and y grids and now it works very well, thanks again u made my evening!

Comment: @JavaHater - Hope you hate java a little bit less :)

Answer (score 0):

To do something like that,exact to your sample, I think you can use the 'Free Design' in NetBeans rather than GridBagLayout and then restrict the ability to resize the application window.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a GridBagLayout. Try a BorderLayout. The label in the NORTH and the tabbed pane in the CENTER.

Or maybe a vertical BoxLayout.

Comment: Sorry but what are you going on about here? GridBagLayout is very good to learn.

Comment: @willcodejavaforfooc, the posted didn't state they where "trying to learn something". I always use the easiest approach to solve a problem. In this case the GridBagLayout is not the easiest solution. I like to give the poster a choice so they understand different approaches. Many newbies, blindly think they have to code a certain way because they copied the code from some place.